# Scala Play Forms: using HLists to get around the 22 fields limitation

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.5

Slick uses a kind of hack with HLists to manage tables that have more than 22 columns, for instance this (auto-generated) row model constructor:

```
type SamplesRow = HCons[Int,HCons[String,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Int,HCons[String,HCons[Int,HCons[Int,HCons[Option[Int],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Boolean,HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[Int],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[Float],HCons[Option[String],HCons[Option[String],HNil]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

def SamplesRow(id: Int, name: String, shortName: Option[String] = None, sampleTypeId: Int, receivedDate: String, projectId: Int, taxoId: Int, quantifMethodId: Option[Int] = None, concentration: Option[Float] = None, volume: Option[Float] = None, description: Option[String] = None, comment: Option[String] = None, istrashed: Boolean = false, commentCustomer: Option[String] = None, createdAt: Option[String] = None, updatedAt: Option[String] = None, createdBy: Option[String] = None, updatedBy: Option[String] = None, poId: Option[Int] = None, `260280Ratio`: Option[Float] = None, `260230Ratio`: Option[Float] = None, rin: Option[Float] = None, concUpdatedAt: Option[String] = None, concUpdatedBy: Option[String] = None): SamplesRow = {
  id :: name :: shortName :: sampleTypeId :: receivedDate :: projectId :: taxoId :: quantifMethodId :: concentration :: volume :: description :: comment :: istrashed :: commentCustomer :: createdAt :: updatedAt :: createdBy :: updatedBy :: poId :: `260280Ratio` :: `260230Ratio` :: rin :: concUpdatedAt :: concUpdatedBy :: HNil
}
```

Can I use the same trick to have a Form hold 24 values? Like in

```
val tableForm: Form[SamplesRow] = Form(
  mapping(
    ID -> ignored(-1),
    NAME -> text,
    SHORT_NAME -> optional(text),
    SAMPLE_TYPE_ID -> number,
    RECEIVED_DATE -> default(text, NOW),
    PROJECT_ID -> number,
    TAXO_ID -> number,
    QUANTIF_METHOD_ID -> optional(number),
    CONCENTRATION -> optional(of[Float]),
    VOLUME -> optional(of[Float]),
    DESCRIPTION -> optional(text),
    COMMENT -> optional(text),
    IS_TRASHED -> default(boolean, false),
    COMMENT_CUSTOMER -> optional(text),
    CREATED_AT -> optional(text),
    UPDATED_AT -> optional(text),
    CREATED_BY -> optional(text),
    UPDATED_BY -> optional(text),
    PO_ID -> optional(number),
    RATIO_260_280 -> optional(of[Float]),
    RATIO_260_230 -> optional(of[Float]),
    RIN -> optional(of[Float]),
    CONC_UPDATED_AT -> optional(text),
    CONC_UPDATED_BY -> optional(text)
  )(SamplesRow)(???)
)
```

I feel like the constructor `def SamplesRow` from above can be used as `apply` method, but what can I use as "`unapply`" ?

I know that I am supposed to use nested mappings, but then I cannot map the result directly to a Slick row model and it sounds silly to write 100 lines of code to implement the conversion so that I can do an insert.

Comment: If I were you. I wouldnt use play forms!

Comment: @RhysBradbury I am about to get rid of them. Do you mean only in my situation, or not to use them in any case?

Comment: Generally just don't haha. Go for a post route with Json body parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tempted to get rid of Forms completely and replace them by a custom JsObject parsing:

```
// Controller Action:
val content = request.body.asJson
val row = rowFromJson(content)

// Somewhere else
import play.api.libs.json._
def rowFromJson(j: JsObject): SamplesRow = {
  SamplesRow(
    (j \ "id").as[Int],
    (j \ "name").as[String]
    ...
  )
}
```

where `SamplesRow` is a Slick `Samples#TableElementType` for a table `Samples <: AbstractTable[_]`.